# Excel: Generating Months Data from Start and End Date

Tags: excel

I would like to use excel to track how many interns I have for each month over the years.

| Name | Division | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | Div A | 12 Jun 2019 | 1 Jan 2020 |
| Ben | Div B | 20 Oct 2020 | 20 Dec 2020 |
| Clare | Div C | 13 Jan 2021 | 13 Jan 2022 |

Is there a way that I can use excel to list the number of months each intern work like below so that I am able to put into a graph how many interns I have each month

| Month/Year | Name | Div |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jun 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Jul 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Aug 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Sep 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Oct 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Nov 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Dec 2019 | Anna | Div A |
| Jan 2020 | Anna | Div A |
| Oct 2020 | Ben | Div B |
| Nov 2020 | Ben | Div B |
| Dec 2020 | Ben | Div B |
| Jan 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Feb 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Mar 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Apr 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| May 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Jun 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Jul 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Aug 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Sep 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Oct 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Nov 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Dec 2021 | Clare | Div C |
| Jan 2022 | Clare | Div C |

Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code assumes that the original data is on `Sheet1` starting in `A1` and puts the result in columns `H:J`.

All that can be adjusted if needed.

```vb
Sub ExpandThings()
Dim arrDataIn As Variant
Dim arrDataOut As Variant
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idxMonth As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        arrDataIn = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        ReDim arrDataOut(1 To 3, 1 To Application.Max(.Columns(4)) - Application.Min(.Columns(3)))
    End With

    For idxRow = LBound(arrDataIn, 1) To UBound(arrDataIn, 1)
        For idxMonth = 0 To DateDiff("m", arrDataIn(idxRow, 3), arrDataIn(idxRow, 4))
            cnt = cnt + 1
            arrDataOut(1, cnt) = Format(DateAdd("m", idxMonth, arrDataIn(idxRow, 3)), "mmm yyyy")
            arrDataOut(2, cnt) = arrDataIn(idxRow, 1)
            arrDataOut(3, cnt) = arrDataIn(idxRow, 2)
        Next idxMonth
    Next idxRow
    
    If cnt > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrDataOut(1 To 3, 1 To cnt)
        Range("H1").Resize(, 3).Value = Array("Month/Name", "Name", "Div")
        Range("H2").Resize(cnt, 3).Value = Application.Transpose(arrDataOut)
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Norie, this works perfectly thanks so much! However I have ta *noob* question. Could you please explain these two lines of VBA code for me please:

ReDim arrDataOut(1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1, 1 To Application.Max(.Columns(4)) - Application.Min(.Columns(3)))
    End With

    For idxRow = LBound(arrDataIn, 1) To UBound(arrDataIn, 1)

Comment: That first line of code isn't in the code I posted. The second line of code  is for looping through the rows of the source data.

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. Sorry I edited the second line of code to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I am trying:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Const NONSENSE As String = "Nonsense"

Public Sub F()
Dim I As Date
Dim S As String
Dim SwitchMonth As Boolean
Dim M As Integer
Dim D1 As Date
Dim D2 As Date

   D1 = "10.10.1990"
   D2 = "01.12.1991"

   If (D1 > D2) Then
      MsgBox ("Failure!")
      Exit Sub
   End If

   M = Month(D1)
   MsgBox (OnMonth(M, Year(D1)))
   SwitchMonth = False
   For I = D1 To D2 Step 1
      
      If Month(I) <> M Then
         M = Month(I)
         MsgBox (OnMonth(M, Year(I)))
      End If
   Next

End Sub

Public Function OnMonth(ByVal M As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer) As String

   If (M < 1) Or (M > 12) Then
      OnMonth = NONSENSE
   End If
   
   Select Case M
      Case 1
         OnMonth = "January"
      Case 2
         OnMonth = "February"
      Case 3
         OnMonth = "March"
      Case 4
         OnMonth = "April"
      Case 5
         OnMonth = "May"
      Case 6
         OnMonth = "June"
      Case 7
         OnMonth = "July"
      Case 8
         OnMonth = "August"
      Case 9
         OnMonth = "September"
      Case 10
         OnMonth = "October"
      Case 11
         OnMonth = "November"
      Case 12
         OnMonth = "December"
   End Select
   
   OnMonth = OnMonth & " " & Y

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain your pictured output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

***Also note the `#"Extracted Month Name"` step.  This creates the text string that you see in the results table. If you want this to be a "real date", delete this last step from the Applied Steps window, and format that column on the Excel Worksheet for the appearance you desire***

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in data
//change table name in next line to reflect actual table name in workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        {{"Name", type text}, {"Division", type text}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),

//create list of dates by month with intervening months (between start and end) = first of the months
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Month/Year", each 
        let 
          StartDate = #date(Date.Year([Start Date]),Date.Month([Start Date]),1),
          EndDate = [End Date],
          mnthList = List.Generate(
                        ()=>StartDate, 
                        each _ <= EndDate, 
                        each Date.AddMonths(_, 1)),

//Replace first and last months in the list with the actual date
          replLast = List.ReplaceRange(mnthList,List.Count(mnthList)-1,1,{[End Date]}),
          replFirst = List.ReplaceRange(replLast,0,1,{[Start Date]})
        in
           replFirst),

//Remove unneeded columns and move the Month/Year column to the beginning
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Start Date", "End Date"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Month/Year", "Name", "Division"}),

//expand the month list into new rows -- one row for each month
    #"Expanded mnthList" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Month/Year"),

//Extract the month name and year as a string for display
//Can omit these steps if you want actual months in the cells
//    in which case you would format them on the worksheet
    #"Extracted Month Name" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded mnthList", {
      {"Month/Year", each Date.MonthName(_) & " " & Text.From(Date.Year(_)), type text}})
in
    #"Extracted Month Name"
```

[image]